# How to correctly include uncertainties in fitting with python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some data points with y uncertainties in python. The data are labeled in python as x,y and yerr.
I need to do a linear fit on that data in loglog scale. As a reference if the fit results are properly, i compare the python results with the ones from Scidavis

I tried curve_fit with

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return np.exp(a* np.log(x)+np.log(b))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y,sigma=yerr)
```

as well as kmpfit with

```
def funcL(p, x):
   a,b = p
   return ( np.exp(a*np.log(x)+np.log(b)) )

def residualsL(p, data):
   a,b=p
   x, y, errorfit = data
   return (y-funcL(p,x)) / errorfit

a0=1
b0=0.1
p0 = [a0,b0]
fitterL = kmpfit.Fitter(residuals=residualsL, data=(x,y,yerr))
fitterL.parinfo = [{}, {}]
fitterL.fit(params0=p0)
```

and when i am trying to fit the data with one of those without uncertainties (i.e setting yerr=1), everything works just fine and the results are identical with the ones from scidavis. But if i set yerr to the uncertainties of the data file i get some disturbing results. 
In python i get i.e. a=0.86 and in scidavis a=0.14. I read something about that the errors are included as weights. Do i have to change anything, in order to calculate the fit correctly? Or what am i doing wrong?

edit: here is an example of a data file (x,y,yerr)

```
3.942387e-02    1.987800e+00    5.513165e-01
6.623142e-02    7.126161e+00    1.425232e+00
9.348280e-02    1.238530e+01    1.536208e+00
1.353088e-01    1.090471e+01    7.829126e-01
2.028446e-01    1.023087e+01    3.839575e-01
3.058446e-01    8.403626e+00    1.756866e-01
4.584524e-01    7.345275e+00    8.442288e-02
6.879677e-01    6.128521e+00    3.847194e-02
1.032592e+00    5.359025e+00    1.837428e-02
1.549152e+00    5.380514e+00    1.007010e-02
2.323985e+00    6.404229e+00    6.534108e-03
3.355974e+00    9.489101e+00    6.342546e-03
4.384128e+00    1.497998e+01    2.273233e-02
```

and the result:

```
in python: 
   without uncertainties: a=0.06216 +/- 0.00650 ; b=8.53594 +/- 1.13985
   with uncertainties: a=0.86051 +/- 0.01640 ; b=3.38081 +/- 0.22667 
in scidavis:
   without uncertainties: a  = 0.06216 +/- 0.08060; b  = 8.53594 +/- 1.06763
   with uncertainties: a  = 0.14154 +/- 0.005731; b  = 7.38213 +/- 2.13653
```

Answer (score 3):

I must be misunderstanding something. Your posted data does not look anything like

```
f(x,a,b) = np.exp(a*np.log(x)+np.log(b))
```

The red line is the result of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`,
the green line is the result of scidavis.

My guess is that neither algorithm is converging toward a good fit, so it is not surprising that the results do not match.

---

I can't explain how scidavis finds its parameters, but according to the definitions *as I understand them*, `scipy` is finding parameters with lower least squares residuals than `scidavis`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(x, a, b):
    return np.exp(a* np.log(x)+np.log(b))

def sum_square(residuals):
    return (residuals**2).sum()

def residuals(p, x, y, sigma):
    return 1.0/sigma*(y - func(x, *p))

data = np.loadtxt('test.dat').reshape((-1,3))
x, y, yerr = np.rollaxis(data, axis = 1)
sigma = yerr

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma = sigma, maxfev = 10000)
print('popt: {p}'.format(p = popt))
scidavis = (0.14154, 7.38213)
print('scidavis: {p}'.format(p = scidavis))

print('''\
sum of squares for scipy:    {sp}
sum of squares for scidavis: {d}
'''.format(
          sp = sum_square(residuals(popt, x = x, y = y, sigma = sigma)),
          d = sum_square(residuals(scidavis, x = x, y = y, sigma = sigma))
      ))

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', x, func(x,*popt), 'r-', x, func(x, *scidavis), 'g-')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr)
plt.show()
```

yields

```
popt: [ 0.86051258  3.38081125]
scidavis: (0.14154, 7.38213)
sum of squares for scipy:    53249.9915654
sum of squares for scidavis: 239654.84276
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed it changes the result a little bit, but unfortunately it is still far away from the scidavis result...

Comment: Could you post some data and the result from scidavis so those of us without scidavis installed can experiment?

Comment: see my edit above. unfortunately i cannot append pictures yet :(

Comment: no, thats right. Plot it in loglog scale and it looks better. This is the extreme case. Other files look more linear.

Comment: No other suggestions? As is said, even if it is not fully linear in loglog scale, the fit of scidavis converges with a reduced chi^2 of 0.4. Its not perfect, but i think that is ok. And if i watch the loglogfit of scidavis, i would have fitted the data exactly the same way (a line through the data and some of the points are above and some under the line), and not has python has done it. This must be reproducable in python. Otherwise it would be quite dissapointing...

Comment: Because of the weighting, it is not easy to intuit the right curve fit. I tried to compute the weighted sum of squares of the residuals and it appears that scipy is finding parameters with lower sum of squares than scidavis. (This is open to debate depending on your definition of `residuals` and `sigma`, which may amount to the whole issue here...)

Comment: Ok, that might be a good information. The question is now can i adjust curve_fit or kmpfit in order to get that weighting? The thing is i have about 1000 data files. Maybe 10% are of that kind. The results of Scidavis would match the expectation i have from the other files (only with error weighting). So it would be quite miserable to fit now all 1000 files with scidavis, since everything must be done manually, whereas in python this is done automatically without adjusting anything.